# Minimum of $ f(\alpha) = \left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^{n}\alpha}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^{n}\alpha}\right)$

Tags: inequality

> Minimum value of $\displaystyle f(\alpha) = \left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^{n}\alpha}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^{n}\alpha}\right)\;,$ Where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\displaystyle \alpha \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

I have solved It using Derivative Test, But that nethod is very Lengthy,

Can we solve it Using Inequality

If yes ,Then plz explain me how can we solve it, Thanks

Comment: Should not the domain be open? That is, $(0,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 3):

The following is **not** a complete answer, but it proves that $f'(\pi/4)=0$ without actally differetiating $f$. I think this should help.

Define for $x\in(-\pi/4,\pi/4)$
$$g(x)=f(x-\pi/4)=\left(1+\frac1{(\frac{\sqrt2}2\sin x-\frac{\sqrt2}2\cos x)^n}\right)\left(1+\frac1{(\frac{\sqrt2}2\sin x+\frac{\sqrt2}2\cos x)^n}\right)$$

Note that
$$g(-x)=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac1{(\frac{\sqrt2}2\sin x+\frac{\sqrt2}2\cos x)^n}\right)(-1)^n\left(1+\frac1{(\frac{\sqrt2}2\sin x-\frac{\sqrt2}2\cos x)^n}\right)=g(x)$$

Therefore, $g$ is an even function. Since $g$ is differentiable at $0$, we have $g'(0)=0$.

Comment: That $g'(0)=0$  doesn't mean that $0$ is the global extremum. At the very least you need to establish the derivative has no other zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution ! And there are no other zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks friends  got it

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)\;, t>0$ Using Jesan Inequality function $f(t)$ is convex function.

So $$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\geq 2\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x+y}\right)$$

Where $x,y\in (0,1)$

So $$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\geq \ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x+y}\right)^2\geq \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}\right)^2$$

So $$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\geq \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}\right)^2$$ and equality hold when $x=y$

So $$\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^ n\alpha}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^n \alpha}\right)\geq \left(1+\frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin 2 \alpha}}\right)^2\geq \left(1+2^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)^2$$

and equality hold when $\displaystyle \sin^n \alpha = \cos^n \alpha\Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\geq \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}\right)^2$ is just Cauchy inequality for $n=2$.