# Find the minimum value of $\left(1+1/\sin^n (a)\right)\left(1+1/\cos^n (a)\right)$ using applications of derivatives

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the minimum value of $\left(1+\cfrac{1}{\sin^n (a)}\right)\left(1+\cfrac{1}{\cos^n (a)}\right)$ using applications of derivatives

I tried to solve it by equating the first derivative to zero to find a maxima but it doesn't simplify. please help.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then the value goes to $-\infty$ when $a\to 0$ from the left.

Comment: One glance and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879895/minimum-of-f-alpha-left1-frac1-sinn-alpha-right-cdot-left1-f) could make this question a  duplicate. However, strictly speaking it isn't.

Comment: In the future, please use $\LaTeX$, see here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference And please put the question in the question, not just the title.  The following link also provides tips on how to ask good questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @SimpleArt: That's not a good reason to change the OP's multiplication to a division, is it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, that was multiplication?  My bad, I'll fix it.

Comment: BITSAT problem?